# Changing the schema of a table in SQLite in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am using SQLite DB to store data in my c# project. I have an existing table which has some records. Now I want to insert two more columns in existing table. How can I insert the data with my C# code for those two columns. Do I need to create the table again or altering the table will do?
The project also has designer.cs corresponding to that table which is getting generated automatically. I want to know how this file is getting generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for changing to schema in sqlite u need to make appropriate changes in .XSD file in your project. This will change the designer.cs automatically and ur schema will be changed. You can search ".xsd" in ur project and can go ahead.